# Remove image from Owl Carousel during lazy load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, owl-carousel-2

**Overview**

So basically I have a carousel that I am populating with images using URLs from a JSON file. I loop through this JSON file and set each URL into a data-src attribute of an image and set it to lazy load in the Owl Carousel. However, I do not know what the URLs provided to me will be, nor do I know if they are broken or not. These are fairly high resolution images, so I would ideally not load them more than once and not load them all in at once.

---

**Problem**

However, an issue arises when I occasionally encounter a broken image link when I make a request for the links. I don't load the images prior to setting it in the carousel, so I don't really have a way to check to see if it's valid or not. **I am trying to find a way to remove the broken images prior to the lazy load of the image without causing a very long load time or any abnormal movements in the carousel.**

---

**What I've tried**

- Loading the images in prior to loading the element. This causes a significant increase in load time which I would like to avoid if unnecessary.
- Using `.onerror` to remove the images when they are loaded in, but broken. This was fast, but causes weird errors in the movement of the carousel. Also, if I want it to be completely reliable, I have to jump back to the prior slide, and jump forward again. For example:

  ```
  $('img.owl-lazy').on("error", function () {
      var carouselData = carousel.data('owl.carousel');
      var index = $(this).parent().index();

      carousel.trigger('remove.owl.carousel', carouselData.relative(index))
          .trigger('refresh.owl.carousel')
          .trigger('prev.owl.carousel')
          .trigger('next.owl.carousel');
  });
  ```

  This ends up creating weird animation effects where it looks like its moving backwards to get to the next slide.
- Loading in each image and adding them to the carousel as they arrive. This did seem to load the images faster, but ended up creating a stacking effect in the images until they were all loaded, in which they were then placed into the carousel correctly.
- Just removing the element associated with that slide using `.remove()`. This ended up causing weird navigation issues with the carousel.

---

If anyone has any strategies that they would recommend I would very much appreciate the advice. Also, if you need more code I would be happy to include it.

---

**Edit 1: Example**

[Here](https://codepen.io/ChaseIngebritson/pen/dePqqR) is a Codepen giving an example of the issue I'm coming across. (I replaced my standard ajax call with a bunch of duck pictures, so in a standard scenario I would not know the URLs being provided in advance.) Also, note that the carousel loads in 3 or 4 of the images towards the beginning of the carousel to provide a bit of a buffer. There may be images with broken links included in this initial buffer as well as towards the end.

Comment: please include a snippet or a fiddle to help us visualize the problem

Comment: Sorry about that, please check the edit towards the bottom of the post for an example displaying my issue.

Comment: when you say *However, an issue arises when I occasionally encounter a broken image link*, what is the issue, is it the very fact that the link is broken?

Comment: I clarified my problem a bit further in the post. The issue isn't necessarily that the link is broken, it's that I don't have a reliable way to remove the image without the user seeing it, or any other abnormal movement, in the carousel.